# request solr to search for special character containing string

Tags: apache, solr

How can I request Solr to search for special characters.

e.g. to search for Strings containing the '@' character

When I am quering

```
"name_tsi : "@*"  AND type_ssi :program"
```

It is giving me all the available entries in the index.

Which I get through

```
"type_ssi :program"
```

I am getting same results in both the cases, but it should filter the result on the basis of (name_tsi : "@*").

And use of back slash \ before @ is not working.

Is there anything I can do in  solrconfig.xml or schema.xml

Comment: How is the name_tsi field analyzed? It might be that the @ is dropped so only the asterisk remains.

Comment: yes Klein,  it escaping the special characters which i pass in my query strings,but i think it can read *
so if i query **News-crime** (name_tsi : News-crime) or **News@crime** (name_tsi : News@crime)  it gives me the same output in both the cases, that ideally i should get only in News-crime and there should be zero result in News@crime.
i think it is only picking alphabetic strings "News" "crime" and searching for it.
i read some where this configuration can be done in schema.xml, but i am not getting how to do it.

Comment: for example i need to search **News@crime** as it is

Comment: Quickest way to do that is to store it in a string field. Then no analysis is being done. But if you want matches on lowercasing etc. you might want to create a new text field.